# Every Vertical Strip Has A Point With Positive Slope

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

Consider a differentiable function $f$ on $[x_0, x_1]$.

Suppose $f(x_0) < f(x_1)$.

It seems intuitively obvious that every vertical strip between $f(x_0)$ and $f(x_1)$ contains a point with positive slope.

i.e. a point $x$ with $f'(x) > 0$ and $a < f(x) < b$

Let the lower bound of this vertical strip be $a$.

Let the upper bound of this vertical strip be $b$.

[image]

This seems like it should be a very common question, I believe it can be proved formally using the intermediate + mean value theorem.

Does anyone have any idea how to prove this?

Comment: I thought this would be obvious, but I'm drawing a blank. One result you might want to think about is Darboux's theorem, which says that the derivative of a differentiable function enjoys the intermediate value property.

Comment: Ummm... "vertical" or "horizontal"??

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think OP means that $f'$ is positive at some point of $f^{-1}(a,b)$ for all $f(x_0) \leq a < b \leq f(x_1)$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins:  Right... so *horizontal strip* it is!

Comment: Another way to rephrase what you want to prove: $A = \{f(x) : x \in [x_0 , x_1] \text{ and } f'(x) > 0 \}$ is dense in $[f(x_0) , f(x_1)]$. I suspect it's actually true that $A = [f(x_0), f(x_1)]$, but, again, the proof eludes me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, judging from your drawing, you probably mean **horizontal** strips not vertical strips.

That aside, this problem is an application of IVT (intermediate value theorem), MVT (mean value theorem) and certain other facts leveraging the continuity of $f$ (e.g. preimages of closed sets are closed).

As $f(x_0) < a < f(x_1)$, by IVT there is some $x_0 < s < x_1$ such that $f(s) = a$. So, the set
$$
S := \{s \in [x_0, x_1] : f(s) = a\} = f^{-1}(\{a\}) \cap [x_0, x_1]
$$ is non-empty, bounded and closed. Thus, $s^\ast := \sup(S)$ is achieved inside $S$ i.e. $f(s^\ast) = a$ and $x_0 \leq s^\ast \leq x_1$ Also, $f(x_1) \neq a$. So in fact $s^\ast < x_1$.

Then, as $a = f(s^\ast) < b < f(x_1)$, yet again by IVT, there is some $s^\ast < t < x_1$ such that $f(t) = b$. So, the set
$$
T := \{t \in [s^\ast, x_1] : f(t) = b\} = f^{-1}(\{b\}) \cap [s^\ast, x_1]
$$ is non-empty, bounded and closed. Thus, $t^\ast := \inf(T)$ is achieved inside $T$ i.e. $f(t^\ast) = b$ and $s^\ast \leq t^\ast \leq x_1$. Also, $f(s^\ast) = a \neq b$. So in fact $s^\ast < t^\ast$.

Finally by MVT, there is some $s^\ast < u < t^\ast$ such that $f'(u) = \frac{f(t^\ast) - f(s^\ast)}{t^\ast - s^\ast} = \frac{b - a}{t^\ast - s^\ast} > 0$.

You must also have $a < f(u) < b$. Otherwise for e.g. if $f(u) \leq a$, then you have the situation $f(u) \leq a < f(x_1)$ so IVT would give you an $u \leq s' < x_1$ such that $f(s') = a$. But then, $s^\ast < u \leq s'$, which is impossible because $s^\ast$ is supposed to be the *largest* $s \in [x_0, x_1]$ such that $f(s) = a$. A similar argument shows $b \leq f(u)$ is also impossible.

Comment: How do you know a < f(u) < b ?

Comment: @AlexanderBullen Why do you need $a < f(u) < b$? Your question was about finding some $x_0 < u < x_1$ with $f'(u) > 0$. If there are extra conditions, include them in your question.

Comment: @0XLR The OP is asking for $x_0 < u < x_1$ with $a < f(u) < b$ and $f'(u) > 0$. He wants a point where the derivative is positive that lives inside the horizontal strip.

Comment: @AlexanderBullen The answer should now account for the extra condition in your edit.